# How i can attach image to send Twitter private message on iOS app?

Tags: ios, twitter

How i can attach image to send Twitter private message on iOS app? I can send text, but in API no parameter for attachments.

Comment: did you use social framework or api

Comment: @iDev i use rest api. (v1.1)